# What is the LIBCURL equivalent to -d?

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

In LIBCURL for PHP what is the equivalent to a basic curl -d?

This is my basic CURL: I need to format it for LIBCURL in PHP:

```
curl -u username:password -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST -d '[{"phoneNumber":"12135551100","message":"Hello World!"}]' "https://api.example.com/v2/texts"
```

I have tried using `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` and `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA`but I can't seem to get my request to work.

Comment: You can use `curlopt_postfield`

Comment: `curlopt_postfields` doesn't work either. I need to post an array. Does that make a difference?

Comment: You can post an array with `curlopt_postfields`

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,array('phoneNumber'=>'23423'));`

Answer (score 2):

The option required is CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS. The specification is the same as the [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html) reference.

There are some PHP examples in the [curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) reference. The simplest way being the following example:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "postvar1=value1&postvar2=value2");
```

Answer (score 0):

My endpoint needed data in the form of an array so this worked.

```
function doPost($url, $user, $password, $params = array()) {
    $authentication = 'Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode("$user:$password");
    $http = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($http, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($http, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($http, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($http, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($http, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($http, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    curl_setopt($http, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json', $authentication));
    return curl_exec($http);
}
```

My array formatted like this:

```
$params = '[{"phoneNumber":"' . $ToNumber . '","message":"' . $msg . '"}]';
```